# Fix a 'nesting mistake' in HTML table created by jinja for loop

Tags: html, jinja2

How do I display a sql table on a website using flask with Jinja template and html tables?

Here is my code for a script "profile.html"

I am having trouble printing the values from table "users". I get the error:

> TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endblock'. You probably
>   made a nesting mistake. Jinja is expecting this tag, but currently
>   looking for 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be
>   closed is 'for'.

I think the problem might lie with the lines `{% for user in users %}` and `{% endfor %}`  which doesnt work with the jinja template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="jumbo">
    <h2>Profile<h2>
  </div>

  <table class="table">
  <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>uid</th>
            <th>firstname</th>
            <th>lastname</th>
            <th>email</th>

          </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          {% for user in users %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ user.uid }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ comment.lastname }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.email }}</td>

          </tr>
    </tbody>  
   </table>    
          {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

How can I edit them to display my SQL table on the web page?

Comment: the error might be in layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<table>` and `<tbody>` opening tags are outside the `for` loop, while the `</table>` and `</tbody>` closing tags are inside the for loop. This means that although you only have one `<table>` opening tag, you're closing that tag after each row. The browser doesn't know what to do with all these extra closing tags, so it renders a table with one row, then renders the rest of the rows outside the table. To fix this, you need to reposition the `{% endfor %}` code to before the `</tbody>` and `</table>` closing tags:

```
{% for user in users %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ user.uid }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.firstname }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.lastname }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The template you've shown would not result in the `TemplateSyntaxError` you indicated, but your code will render incorrectly without this change.

Comment: @ThomasHobohm If it did indeed fix the issue, then the OP should be updated to more accurately state what the issue is. Otherwise this is of no use to any future visitor. Noone here is saying your suggestion is wrong, and any SO user can offer critique or suggestions for improvement in comments - it does not mean they think they are a moderator. "SO is moderated by you".